I don't think he himself even knows which number the current one is
The man fires his carers because of small mistakes, too. So far, he has fired many. I don't think he even knows ........ the current one is.
What I want to say in the last sentence is to emphasize the abundance of carers fired, focusing on the unknownness of actual number of them. In other words, it is impossible for the man himself to even know which number the last one falls onto, because he doesn't know the exact total number of the previous ones.
I have been thinking about it to find a practical way to to say it. And the best I could think of is:
"I don't think he himself even knows which number the current one is."
Though, I am not sure if it sounds all right for native english speakers.

You've said up a template sentence that just make it very hard to fill in the blank to give a clear and meaningful result. Yes, you could say, "... what number the current one is". But that would be awkward, because we don't normally talk about "the number of an employee" to mean how many before him were fired. If you just said to me, "What is that employee's number?" with no context, I would take you to mean his employee ID number, not how many people had held that position before him.
Most English speakers would say something more like, "... even he doesn't know how many he has fired" or "... how many he has gone through".
